# PostgreSQL error, type Java_Object does not exist

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I am using PostgreSQL and SQL PowerArchitect to design a physical datamodel. As I am using Hibernate which can directly persist Java objects in the database, I thought of using Java_Object as the type in SQL PowerArchitect. When I execute the query, I get this error. Kindly let me know if the type actually doesnt exist in PostgreSQL or I am making some mistake. Googling I am unable to find many reference to the data type.

```
CREATE TABLE public.Product_Info (
                productinfoid VARCHAR NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('public.product_info_productinfoid_seq'),
                productbasic VARCHAR NOT NULL,
                Product_Tags JAVA_OBJECT,
                Product_Categories JAVA_OBJECT,
                Product_Ship_Time JAVA_OBJECT,
                CONSTRAINT productinfoid PRIMARY KEY (productinfoid, productbasic)
)

INFO  15-09 10:12:04,300 - sql statement failed: ERROR: type "java_object" does not exist
```

Comment: I am using postgresql-9.3-1102.jdbc41 Drivers.

Comment: `java_object` is not datatype in Postgres (all datatypes are documented here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype.html). Why would you want to store a complete (serialized) Object as a single column in the database. This is almost always a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

When creating tables you need to use column types that are supported by your database, like: CHAR, VARCHAR NUMERIC, BLOB, etc

Hibernate takes care of the [the object type to database column type mapping](http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-hibernate-types/).

You need FKs for these relationships:

- Product_Tags,
- Product_Categories

and probably a DATE/TIME/TIMESTAMP for this one:

- Product_Ship_Time

The `JAVA_OBJECT` is for storing Java `Class` objects not Java `Object` instances!

Check [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.JdbcTypeJavaClassMappings](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/4.3.3.Final/org/hibernate/type/descriptor/sql/JdbcTypeJavaClassMappings.java):

```
jdbcJavaClassMappings.put( Class.class, Types.JAVA_OBJECT );
```

So this type would be useful when fetching a Class object type from a database column (e.g. VARCHAR).

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand your point. My question is, is Java_Object not supported by PostgresSQL? I know hibernate can take care, but by directly persisting objects, it would make some of my tasks simpler.

Comment: Well, there is an option in SQL PowerArchitect. Thus the question.